# How to get a patent invalidated?

Tags: patentability, claims, invalidation

Recently while I was writing up a patent, I discovered that another person has written a patent that is so badly and vaguely worded that it could be used to cover my invention. Whereas I offer clear details about what comes before what etc., this other person does not but claims the invention anyway and was granted a patent.
He also begins almost every sentence in the summary with "Some embodiments comprise" as if to trying to make the patent so general as to cover everything. The way he words Claim 1, it appears he's trying to patent the microprocessor, 30 years after it was invented. What to do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. In order to have a possibility to address your question we will need to know what patent document you are referring to. Please edit your question to include the patent or publication number.

Comment: "Some embodiments comprise . . . " is a *very* frequently used phrase in patent specifications.

Comment: Bayer CropScience team claimed different patents from 2009 and 2014 on biological control of soil microorganisms using bacterial agents these findings were not original and are already published. A Tunisian patent including similar claims is protecting a Tunisian biological product using Bacillus synergetic action. You can find this patent at INNORPI TUNISIA (Patent number 18878 deposit on the 22nd November 2004 under the number SN04228) concerning an inventive composition effective on nematodes, fungi and enhancing the root system of plant.
We believe that Bayer is coping our finding on bacte

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. This site is *not* a channel for communication with the USPTO.